# Transpose of a matrix using Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What is the transpose of a matrix:**

In linear algebra, the transpose of a matrix is an operator which flips a matrix over its diagonal; that is, it switches the row and column indices of the matrix A by producing another matrix, often denoted by Aᵀ.

**Code**

```
dimension = int(input())
matrix = []
transpose = []
for row in range(dimension):
    entry = list(map(int,input().split()))
    matrix.append(entry)
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension):
        transpose.append(matrix[j][i])
m = 0
n = dimension 

for x in range(dimension+1):
    
    row = transpose[m:n]
    list1 = [str(item) for item in row]
    string2 = " ".join(list1)
    print(string2)
    m = n
    n = n + dimension
```

**My question**

What all modifications I can do to this code to make it better furthermore efficient?

Comment: Example input and output would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You're converting the matrix elements to int and then back to string without doing anything with the ints, so that's just wasteful.

Anyway, the usual way to transpose is `zip`. Demo including mock input:

```
input = iter('''3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9'''.splitlines()).__next__

matrix = [input().split() for _ in range(int(input()))]

for column in zip(*matrix):
    print(*column)
```

Output:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```py
dimension = int(input())
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(dimension)]
transpose = [[matrix[j][i] for j in range(dimension)] for i in range(dimension)]
```

PD: This still has to pass by every item on the matrix but it is a little more compact code, and if you're used to python you could find it a little more legible.

Comment: Other than code is more compact is there a performance improvement, does the code run faster?

Comment: Practically this code does less iterations, `2n^2` where `n` is the dimension (yours do `3n^2`) But in terms of algorithmic complexity this is still `O(n^2)`.